# How to add custom tab in edit form in admin magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1

In the custom edit form, I want to add a custom tab in admin form.

[image]

Someone plz help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add custom tab in the custom form in admin by  following the below mentioned link:

https://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-2.html

Comment: This is old way of doing things

Answer (score 1):

Try below way.

Follow [Create UI form](https://webkul.com/blog/create-ui-form-magento2-part-1/) link to create simple form without tab structure.

Now replace below code in a given below form.

> Namespace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/employee_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">employee_form_form.employee_form_form_data_source</item>
        <!--            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">employee_form_form.employee_form_form_data_source</item>-->
    </item>
    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Label Options</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">employee_form_form</item>
    </item>
    <item name="reverseMetadataMerge" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>        
</argument>
<settings>
    <buttons>
        <button class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Productlabel\Edit\BackButton" name="back"/>
        <button class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Productlabel\Edit\DeleteButton" name="delete"/>
        <button class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Productlabel\Edit\SaveButton" name="save"/>
        <button class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Productlabel\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton" name="save_and_continue"/>
        <button class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Productlabel\Edit\Duplicate" name="duplicate"/>
    </buttons>        
    <layout>
        <navContainerName>left</navContainerName>
        <type>tabs</type>
    </layout>
    <dataScope>data</dataScope>
    <deps>
        <dep>employee_form_form.employee_form_form_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
<dataSource name="employee_form_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\Productlabel\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">employee_form_form_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">productlabel_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">productlabel_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="managelabels/productlabel/save"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<fieldset name="general">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">General Info</label>
    </settings>
    <field name="productlabel_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Productlabel ID</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">data</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">productlabel_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="labelname" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label Name</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">data</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">labelname</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>        
</fieldset>
```

Let me know if you have any query/concern.

I hope it helps!

**Note:** Make sure you have created a route, controller, model & resource model and blok file. I have share only code to how to add Tab in form.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I have done it already by using [this blog](https://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-2.html) @Chirag Patel

Comment: OK, nop! You can also post your answer here :)